# Is there any way to rotate the bytes of a matrix using other matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, aes

I'm implementing a modified version of AES in python... I need to rotate the elements of a 128-bit round key using another 128-bit key. The first matrix in the picture represents the round key, the second one represents the other key.

[image: Matrix representation]

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply on the right the transpose of the first matrix with the following matrix to swap the columns:

```
|0 0 0 1|
|0 0 1 0|
|0 1 0 0|
|1 0 0 0|
```

Something like this:

```
|54 77 6f 20|T     |0 0 0 1|     |20 4e 4f 54| 
|4f 6e 65 20|   @  |0 0 1 0|  =  |54 69 6e 77| 
|4e 69 6e 65|      |0 1 0 0|     |77 6e 65 6f| 
|20 54 77 6f|      |1 0 0 0|     |6f 65 20 20|
```

Use the linalg package of your choice.